# Glossary of a book

Tags: python, string, list, slice

i want to print title and subtitle of a book based on the input , where 1x'#' means title and 2x'#' means subtitle

input:

mylist=['# algorithm','blah basfafasfsa','## Sorting','xascxas',"# Data structrues","# BST"]

output:

1. algorithm

1.1 Sorting

2. Data structures

this is what I tried but unable to get the desired output:

```
      def index(mylist):
        count=0
        count1=0
        for item in mylist:
                if item.startswith("#"):
                        count+=1
                        print(str(count+"."+item[2:]))
                elif item.startswith("##"):
                        count1+=1
                        print(str(count+"."+count1+"."+item[2:]))
```

Comment: You should provide more intel about the source of your "mylist". Are your producing it yourself? Can you guarantee it will not contain entries with more than 2 '#'? Will there always be a space after '#'?

Answer (score 0):

You need to interchange your conditions since `startswith("#")` will always be true for both the strings `#abc` and `##abc`, also, re-initialise the sub-topic counter when you encounter a new topic. This code works:

```
def index(mylist):
    count = 0
    count1 = 0
    for item in mylist:
        if item.startswith("##"):
            count1 += 1
            print(f"{count}.{count1}{item[2:]}")
        elif item.startswith("#"):
            count += 1
            count1 = 0
            print(f"{count}.{item[2:]}")
mylist=['# algorithm', 'blah basfafasfsa', '## Sorting', 'xascxas', "# Data structrues", "## Trees", "# BST"]
```

Output:

```
1. algorithm
1.1 Sorting
2. Data structrues
2.1 Trees
3. BST
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried this one using formatting, I just started coding, correct me if I am wrong.

```
def index(mylist):
        count=0
        count1=0
        for item in mylist:
                if item.startswith("#")and "##" not in item:
                        count+=1
                        print("{count}.{item}".format(count=count,item=item[2:]))
                elif item.startswith("#") and "##" in item:
                        count1+=1
                        print("{count}.{count1}.{item}".format(count=count,count1=count1,item=item[2:]))
```

Comment: @RomainVincent there is nothing wrong in doing that.

Comment: I don't know why my comment has been deleted. It was here to explain why I downvoted this answer, and to educate @t j6789 as to why this answer is not helpful. Personally, I come to stackoverflow to seek valuable answers. I won't answer on topics that I don't master and I expect others to do the same. The output of the code in this answer is incorrect. `item[2:]` is wrong if the line starts with "## ". The order of if statements is sub optimal and requires additional conditions. the str.format method is suboptimal as well. And more.